# php doesn’t load gd extension in Dockerfile after copying custom php.ini

Tags: php, docker, gd

I have a Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

RUN apk update

COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

RUN /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install  mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
RUN apk upgrade --update && apk add \
            freetype-dev \
            libjpeg-turbo-dev \
            libmcrypt-dev \
            libpng-dev \
        && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
        && /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install gd

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o composer-setup.php

RUN php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x
RUN apk add --no-cache nodejs

RUN apk add yarn
WORKDIR /var/www


EXPOSE 9000
```

Before copying my custom php.ini the Gd Exension was loaded.

After copying custom php.ini the Gd Extension is missing.

Is there a setting in php.ini that I could have forgotten?

Comment: Glad you found an answer! Some comment on why you didn't get one before: Problem is that you use a `php.ini` that may be wrong, but you didn't include it in your question! How should anyone tell if it's wrong if you don't supply the info? Also, your Dockerfile should not contain unnecessary stuff, like e.g. the nodejs installation but it should be a [mcve]. In general, as a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Found something that seems to work for me. I've created an uploads.ini file with the following content:

file_uploads = On 
memory_limit = 64M 
upload_max_filesize = 64M 
post_max_size = 64M 
max_execution_time = 600

And than mount the File

-v /var/docker/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini